# Using JPA/Hibernate and Entity update column on unique contraint violation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a PUT call that, via `@RequestBody`, will map the payload to the below Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"clientId", "reasonCode"}))
public class DeviceInfo implements Serializable {   
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private int clientId;

    private String reasonCode;

    private int deviceValue;

    ... Getters and Setters here ....
}
```

For the DAO layer I have this simple Interface

```
public interface DeviceInfoDao extends JpaRepository<DeviceInfo, Long> {

}
```

which using Spring gets `@Autowired` into my Service layer and saves the Object to the DB with

```
deviceInfo = deviceInfoDao.save(deviceInfo);
```

The issue I am running into is, I could later have another PUT call where the payload is the same except this time the deviceValue is different. Currently it will throw an Exception because the `@UniqueConstraint` was violated.

However, what I would prefer is that an update happens when DeviceInfoDao.save() gets called rather than an Exception getting thrown. I am new to JPA and Hibernate so if someone could please give "best practice" or the cleanest way to do this I would greatly appreciate it.

As a side note -

1. I know throwing an Exception (or sending some kind of error) and forcing the user to use the `PATCH` HTTP method would probably be the best practices scenario here but requirements dictate I do it this way.
2. The caller won't know the auto-generated id value that was produced so having them send that on the next call is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box mechanism that will do this for you. A common way to handle this situation is to first do a search by input parameters, and depending on the output do a `save` or `update`

```
DeviceInfo deviceInfo = deviceInfoDao.findByClientIdAndReasonCode(clientId, reasonCode);
if (deviceInfo == null) {
    deviceInfo = deviceInfoDao.save(deviceInfo);
} else {
    deviceInfo.setDeviceValue(deviceValue);
    deviceInfoDao.update(deviceInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I ended up implementing this is slightly different than the accepted answer and I put here in case it may help anyone else.

As suggested I added this line to my `DeviceInfoDao` Interface:

```
DeviceInfo findByClientIdAndReasonCode(clientId, reasonCode);
```

Then my Service layer looks something like this:

```
public DeviceInfo saveOrUpdateDeviceInfo(DeviceInfo deviceInfo) {
    DeviceInfo previousDeviceInfo = deviceInfoDao.findByClientIdAndReasonCode(clientId, reasonCode);

    if(previousDeviceInfo != null) {
        deviceInfo.setId(previousDeviceInfo.getId());
    }

    // Will also update if exists
    deviceInfo = deviceInfoDao.save(deviceInfo);    

    return deviceInfo
}
```